# Read Apache FOP config and fonts in OSGi blueprint container

Tags: apache, fonts, apache-fop

I have an OSGi blueprint container with Apache FOP dependency. When I generate PDF with default configuration there are problems with russian symbols (#### instead text). In not OSGi test application this problem have easy fix: I use custom fop.xconf config file and two arial*.ttf font files in same directory. Auto-detect in fop.xconf fixes this problem too.

But in OSGi blueprint container I can not read conf file from bundle resources. Can anyone show me an example how to read xconf and fonts from blueprint container? Or how can I configure fonts programmatically without resources reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found the solution.
We cannot use File() with "bundleresource://..." path, but we can use URI():

```
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FOP_XCONF_FILE);
        fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(url.toURI(), url.openStream());
```

In this case we open conf-file input stream from our bundle resources and pass it to special FopFactory.newInstance() definition. Fop.xconf XML with  element works like a charm.